# Named anchors not working with dynamic html and jquery

Tags: jquery, anchor

I am trying to add a html snippet dynamically which contains named anchors and destinations via jquery append('html') method

None of the named links work after the append. The newly added content is visible on the page, but the links dont work. Is it because these tags were added dynamically, or am I doing something wrong here? However, all server side generated named anchors work fine.

simplified html:

```
<a href="#tab">Foo</a>

<div id="tab"></div>

("#testButton").click(function() {
   $('#mainSegmentDiv').append("html")
});
```

Comment: You need to include the rest of the relevant code. What you've provided so far isn't enough.

Comment: definitely need more code and define "don't work"

Comment: Also would help to know what web browsers you have tested it in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anchors appended with JavaScript *should* work as anchors (in that clicking them *should* take you to whatever location is specified in its `href` attribute), but if you're trying to use an tag-name, `id` or `class` to select them, they won't 'work' because they weren't present in the DOM when the event handlers were bound:

[JS Fiddle demo (demonstrates non-working code)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/95Xn3/).

Without specific knowledge of your HTML, or what you're doing, I can only offer you this suggestion:

```
$('body').on('click','a',function(){
    // do something
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo (demonstrates working code)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/95Xn3/1/).

The `on()` method attaches the `click` event (in this case) to the `body` element and relies on event propagation to work, in that the click bubbles up to the `body` and then works out where it came from and if it matches the given selector (the `a` in this case, you can use `id`, `class` or any valid jQuery selector). If it matches the selector the function the events/functions (in this case that's the `// do something` comment) is executed.

Ideally, instead of using the `$('body')` you'd use the closest parent-element to those elements you later add to the DOM that exist at the time of event-binding (usually `$(document).ready()`).

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Thanks, I used the on() to achieve the click action for my href element.

Answer (score -1):

You dont worte `$` seletor sign. Beginign for line

```
$("#testButton").click(function() {
```